# How to make libGDX background transparent in Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx, glsurfaceview

Our Android project now needs to generate a game in activity with transparent background.

I notice that libGDX use GLSurfaceView to draw, and I know it's able to make GLSurfaceView background transparent by `setZOrderOnTop(true)` and `getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT)`

But it is not working in libGDX. I guess it influences by the function `Gdx.gl.glClearColor()` which always invokes in `render()`, and it seems like the alpha channel invalid in `Gdx.gl.glClearColor()`. When I set transparent color `Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0)`, the background will always be black. And If I delete this, the render result comes to error.

So I wonder is there a way to make libGDX background transparent?

Thank you all.

Comment: LibGDX background transparent onto what? It could only be another application that you overlay. Overlays are described here https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/design/overlays . A window cannot exist without a garden.

Comment: @londonBadger I mean, I want to use ``initializeForView`` function in libGDX to get the GLSurfaceView, and add this view to my activity. The problem is GLSurfaceView support alpha channel, and libGDX support argb, but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally made libGDX background transparent by the following code:

```
// add this to your AndroidApplication
AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
config.a = 8; // default is 0
View view = initializeForView(new YourApplicationAdapter(), config);
if (view instanceof SurfaceView) {
    SurfaceView sv = (SurfaceView) view;
    sv.setZOrderOnTop(true);
    sv.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
}
setContentView(view);
```

```
// add this to your ApplicationAdapter
public void render() {
    // other codes
    ScreenUtils.clear(0, 0, 0, 0);
    // other codes
}
```

And I find a good way to discuss what you want about libGDX by [Discord](https://libgdx.com/community/discord/).